# Why is this field validation a type mismatch?

Tags: scala, types

I am having trouble understanding why scala will let me write some field validation happily with this:

```
field -> text().verifying("declaration.additionalDocument.documentTypeCode.unacceptableCode", f => isEmpty(f) or !documentCodesNotAcceptable.contains(f))
```

But not when I do this:

```
text().verifying("declaration.additionalDocument.documentTypeCode.unacceptableCode", isEmpty or !documentCodesNotAcceptable.contains(_))
```

In the second case I get a compilation error telling me `type mismatch; found   : String => Boolean required: Boolean`

But why? How is the second way different from the first?

Comment: Because the second expands as `isEmpty.or(x => !documentCodesNotAcceptable.contains(x))` That is why the `_` syntax is in my black list,

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I see. So I'm assuming `x => !documentCodesNotAcceptable.contains(x)` doesn't resolve to a boolean because there is no value for `x`?

Comment: No, is more simple than that. `or` expects a `Boolean` not a `Function` no matter what that `Function returns.`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Ah I get it now. Further, can I ask for clarification why you don't like the `_` syntax - do you always prefer anonymous functions?

Comment: I don't like it for exactly this kind of question, people get confused by it or they have working code and make some small change, and then it fails with a weird type error. So I usually prefer lambdas, but I do use the `_` when the lambda is too small like `foos.map(_.bar)` or `foo.reduce(_ + _)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument to `verifying` appears to be a predicate. That is, a function that takes a value and returns `true` or `false`, which is a common feature of validation frameworks.

In the first example the predicate is

```
f => isEmpty(f) or !documentCodesNotAcceptable.contains(f)
```

which parses as

```
f => (isEmpty(f) or !documentCodesNotAcceptable.contains(f))
```

This is a perfectly reasonable predicate that first tests `f` with  `isEmpty` and if that fails, does the second test.

In the second example the predicate is this:

```
isEmpty or !documentCodesNotAcceptable.contains(_)
```

which (as explained in the comments) expands to

```
(x => isEmpty(x)) or (x => !documentCodesNotAcceptable.contains(x))
```

So this expression is trying to `or` two functions together, which isn't supported.

The solution is to go with the first version :)